# Ruby: at given an index in a 2d array, replace the first element in the subarray at that index

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a 2d array that looks like:

```
array = [["apples", 10], ["oranges", 12], ["peaches", 15], ["lemons", 7]]
```

I want to replace some of the strings in `array`, (leaving the second position in `array` unchanged) with the help of another 2d array that that contains the strings I want to use as replacements and in the second position is the index where I want to put the replacement, it looks like

```
replacements = [["blankets", 1], ["shoes", 3]]
```

so I want to put `blankets` in the first position of the array at index 1 in `array` etc. the output to look like

```
output = [["apples", 10], ["blankets", 12], ["peaches", 15], ["shoes", 7]]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should do it:

```
replacements.each{|r| array[r[1]][0] = r[0] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
replacements.each{|e, i| array[i][0] = e}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single loop would do the job:

```
replacements.each { |r| array[r[1]][0] = r[0] if array[r[1]] }
```